# How to calculate the number of seconds between two ISO 8601 datetime in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have 2 datetime strings in ISO 8601 format e.g. `1900-01-01 00:00:00+00:00` and `2020-03-27 23:59:59+11:00`.
How can I calculate the number of seconds between these 2 datetime strings using only Excel or Excel VBA?

All the answers I come across calculates the date part only, eventhough the questions asked for **time**stamp.

```
Function TOUNIX(dt) As Long
    TOUNIX = DateDiff("s", "1/1/1970", dt)
End Function
```

Comment: how does the +11:00 affect the 23:59:59?  Do you need to subtract the 11 to get in comon time of +0, or do you need to add 11 hours?

Comment: unix timestamp is expected to be in UTC, so the +11:00 should be subtracted. This is what I think should be the logic.

Answer (score 1):

Broken down for understanding/educational purposes:

- `LEFT(A1,FIND("+",A1)-1)-1` - extracts the date
- `(VALUE(LEFT(A1,FIND("+",A1)-1)-1)` - converts date to a number (`-1` to account for the first second being `0`)
- `(LEFT(MID(A1,FIND("+",A1)+1,5),2)` - extract the hour from the timezone
- `RIGHT(MID(A1,FIND("+",A1)+1,5),2)` - extracts the minutes from the timezone
- `/60` - 60 minutes in an hour
- `/24` - 24 hours in a day
- `IF(LEFT(RIGHT(A1,6),1)="-",1,-1)` - extract the timezone modifier to determine whether the timezone adds or subtracts from value
- Combined to this point, we have the number converted value of the date
- `* 86400` - The amount of seconds in a day

---

```
=(VALUE(LEFT(A1,FIND("+",A1)-1)-1)+((LEFT(MID(A1,FIND("+",A1)+1,5),2)+(RIGHT(MID(A1,FIND("+",A1)+1,5),2)/60))/24)*IF(LEFT(RIGHT(A1,6),1)="-",1,-1))*86400
```

---

Where you are starting with 0, you won't need to subtract from another date. If you wanted to anyway, just duplicate the formula as needed.

Comment: Mech, can the timezone part ever be "-"?

Comment: Yes. If we are starting with GMT.

Answer (score 1):

you will want to look at the following functions.

For text manipulations:

- [LEFT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/left-leftb-functions-9203d2d2-7960-479b-84c6-1ea52b99640c)
- [RIGHT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/right-rightb-functions-240267ee-9afa-4639-a02b-f19e1786cf2f)
- [MID](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/mid-midb-functions-d5f9e25c-d7d6-472e-b568-4ecb12433028)
- [FIND](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/find-findb-functions-c7912941-af2a-4bdf-a553-d0d89b0a0628)
- [SEARCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/search-searchb-functions-9ab04538-0e55-4719-a72e-b6f54513b495)
- [Concatenate](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CONCATENATE-function-8F8AE884-2CA8-4F7A-B093-75D702BEA31D) or &

For date manipulation:

- [Datevalue](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DATEVALUE-function-DF8B07D4-7761-4A93-BC33-B7471BBFF252)
- [Date](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DATE-function-E36C0C8C-4104-49DA-AB83-82328B832349)
- [Year](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/year-function-c64f017a-1354-490d-981f-578e8ec8d3b9)
- [Month](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MONTH-function-579A2881-199B-48B2-AB90-DDBA0EBA86E8)
- [Day](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DAY-function-8A7D1CBB-6C7D-4BA1-8AEA-25C134D03101)

For time manipulation:

- [Timevalue](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/timevalue-function-0b615c12-33d8-4431-bf3d-f3eb6d186645?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)
- [Time](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TIME-function-9A5AFF99-8F7D-4611-845E-747D0B8D5457)
- [Hour](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/HOUR-function-A3AFA879-86CB-4339-B1B5-2DD2D7310AC7)
- [Minute](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/minute-function-af728df0-05c4-4b07-9eed-a84801a60589?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)
- [Second](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/second-function-740d1cfc-553c-4099-b668-80eaa24e8af1)

You have a couple of options.  You can either strip out each individual value and place it in the appropriate date/time individual function or rearrange the date and time as a string that is identifiable by the time/date value functions.

A little background on date and time in Excel.  Date are stored as an integer.  1 represented 1900/1/1, 2 represents 1900/1/2 and so on.  time is stored as a decimal representing fraction of a day.  00:00 is midnight and stores as zero ,  12:00 noon is stored as 0.5 to represent half the day.  24:00 is not an official Excel time, though some function will work with it.  To test if a date/time is stored as text or as an excel number, you can test the value of the cell with something like `ISTEXT(A1)`, change the formatting to general and  see if the display of the cell info changes, and least reliable is to look at the justification of the information in a cell which is left aligned by default for text and right aligned by default for numbers.

Lets assume your strings are stored in A1 and A2

Because Datevalue can be a little finicky and depends a bit on system settings to determine mm vs dd I go with the method of stripping the individual components.  In your case because everything has leading zeros the position of month, day, hour, minute and seconds can be hard coded instead of searching the string starting position of each based of key characters like -, :, +, and space.

Grab the year:

```
=LEFT(A1,4)
```

Grab the month:

```
=MID(A1,6,2)
```

Grab the Day:

```
=MID(A1,9,2)
```

Make the date by dropping the results into DATE as follows:

```
=DATE(LEFT(A1,4),MID(A1,6,2),MID(A1,9,2))
```

Grab the hour:

```
=MID(A1,12,2)
```

Grab the minutes:

```
=MID(A1,15,2)
```

Grab the seconds:

```
=MID(A1,18,2)
```

Make the time by dropping the results into TIME as follows:

```
=TIME(MID(A1,12,2),MID(A1,15,2),MID(A1,18,2))
```

To grab the timezone I will use TIMEVALUE to demonstrate the other method.  This will convert the timezone time or decimal value instead of text like the operations above.

Grab the timezone:

```
=TIMEVALUE(RIGHT(A1,5)*IF(LEFT(RIGHT(A1,6))="-",-1,1)
```

Then you just need to combine the results together to get the whole thing in an excel date and time format:

```
=DATE(LEFT(A1,4),MID(A1,6,2),MID(A1,9,2))+TIME(MID(A1,12,2),MID(A1,15,2),MID(A1,18,2))-TIMEVALUE(RIGHT(A1,5))*IF(LEFT(RIGHT(A1,6))="-",-1,1)
```

Now that the string is converted to an excel date you need to take the difference in the cells noting that the result is days.  Then you need to convert it to seconds by multiplying it by 24*60*60 = 86400.

So if you put the results in B1 and B2 then the formula for difference in seconds would be:

```
=(B2-B1)*24*60*60
```

In the example below its (F14-F12).  Also note that the cells displaying time or date and time have had custom formating applied to them to dispaly 24 hour clock or date and time combined.

[image: POC]

Comment: @Mech two different routes to get to the same answer.  Only thing I was not sure of is if you needed to add 11 to the time or subtract it to get it to GMT

Comment: This doesn't work in localized versions of Excel due to a long known missing feature to be able to switch the function language without much hassle. The decision to translate functions such as LEFT to LINKS is such a poor choice.